# docker buildx oci output

Tags: docker, build, oracle-call-interface

Could someone please help me understand how to get `docker buildx build -o type=oci,dest=/tmp/foo.tar .` to work correctly? I keep getting this error, which means nothing to me.

```
$ sudo docker buildx build -o type=oci,dest=/tmp/test-oci.tar -f .buildkite/scripts/Dockerfile-amd64 .
OCI exporter feature is currently not supported for docker driver. Please switch to a different driver (eg. "docker buildx create --use")
```

I then tried

```
$ sudo docker buildx create --driver docker-container --use oci
```

but now I get

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
error during connect: Get http://oci:2375/v1.24/containers/buildx_buildkit_romantic_jang10/json: dial tcp: lookup oci on 172.18.96.1:53: no such host
```

I am quite obviously missing something here. I didn't see any good examples in the README on [github](https://github.com/docker/buildx), so please help :)

Answer (score 8):

OK, I eventually figured this out.

First thing I didn't understand is that the `docker-container` driver wants to get a build image name, so that it can start up.  Second thing, I didn't understand was you can use `docker inspect --bootstrap` to get the driver bootstrapped and running so that it can accept work requests.

This is the full recipe basically copied out of my history:

```sh
sudo docker buildx create --driver docker-container --driver-opt image=moby/buildkit:master,network=host
sudo docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
sudo docker buildx use $SOME_BUILD_NAME
sudo docker buildx build -o type=oci,dest=/tmp/test-oci.tar -f /path/to/Dockerfile .
```

The `$SOME_BUILD_NAME` will be randomly assigned by docker when it runs the `create` command; you can assign your own name if you pass the `--name MYNAME` flag though.

Hope this helps someone else figure it out.